# http requests failing after ionic build android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have referred https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist and added below to my config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.0"/>
  <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
  <!-- A wildcard can be used to whitelist the entire network,
     over HTTP and HTTPS.
     *NOT RECOMMENDED* -->
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
```

I also have the below permission in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And below is the CSP declaration in the index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
        content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;script-src 'self' localhost:35729 84.254.133.91:8080 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';connect-src *">
```

And the server is running @ 84.254.133.91:8080

Here is the code with http post call:

```
var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: $rootScope.labels.IP + $rootScope.labels.USER_ID_CREATE_URL,

                data: {
                    userId: $scope.newUserIdCreate.username,
                    password: $scope.newUserIdCreate.password,

                }
            };

            var res = $http(req);
            res.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("request success:" + JSON.stringify({ data: data }));

            });

            res.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("request failed:" + JSON.stringify({ data: data }));

            });
```

None of the $http requests are going through. I have spent nearly 2 days and referred 'n' number of articles but still can't crack this issue.

Further, I added a href link to 'google/facebook', and I am able to access these websites from the App.

Using the web app by running 'ionic serve' works perfectly fine. From the Android apk, none of the requests are hitting the server.

What is the missing configuration?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to your problem? I have a similar situation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870757/ionic-app-on-android-not-sending-http-requests

Comment: On further investigation, I see my requests hitting the Tomcat server but getting rejected with 403. I then came across this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224508/cors-issue-with-tomcat-and-android-webview And now following the steps in the above question to fix my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much investigation over several days, the issue was same as that [CORS issue with Tomcat and Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224508/cors-issue-with-tomcat-and-android-webview)

Adding the CordovaOriginWrapper as mentioned in one of the answers in the above question resolved the issue.

This is tricky and the ionic documentation never talks about this behavior. Ionic documentation needs to be updated with this behavior.

Comment: my app worked but when upgrade gradle cant connect and call post method from wordpress rest apis, please help me